# MySQL 5.6 InnoDB count, group by, having and order by return wrong result

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, innodb, having

I have a problem with a big query but tried to simplify it and found similar strange behaviour:

```
select concat(a.col1,a.col2) as b,
       count(a.id) as c
from test as a
group by a.id
having b = "644591"
order by b
```

The same query returns no results on 5.6 InnoDB but 5.5 MyISAM returns one correct match.

If you remove the "order by b" it returns correct on InnoDB too.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `col2` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

id|col1    |col2
 1|        |644591
 2|70083531|1226109
```

Comment: Your String should be in single quotes: having b = '644591'

Comment: @Jens - Can you elaborate on why this is so?

Comment: @Strawberry From [Mysql Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html): "If the ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode is enabled, string literals can be quoted only within single quotation marks because a string quoted within double quotation marks is interpreted as an identifier. "

Comment: @Jens OK - but why does this work?? `select concat(a.col1,a.col2) as b, count(a.id) as c from test a where concat(a.col1,a.col2) = "644591"
group by concat(a.col1,a.col2) order by b;` http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/172fc/10

Comment: It produce the same result with single quotes on the having

Comment: MySQL 5.6.25 fixed a bug with HAVING and ORDER BY. You should try this version

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
select concat(a.col1,a.col2) as b,
       count(a.id) as c
from test a
where concat(a.col1,a.col2) = '644591'
group by concat(a.col1,a.col2)
order by b;
```

Comment: The reason for the question is that the big query which did not return the correct rows already have where and grouping and THEN needs to apply having filter on the result. A simple query like this should return the same result on innodb and myisam.